# Minimal "run this command in this docker image" jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins

There is a docker image whose name is IMAGE_NAME.

I want a Jenkins job to `docker pull IMAGE_NAME` and then `docker run IMAGE_NAME /bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/my_startup arg1 arg2 arg3`

I tried a few variations of a Jenkinsfile based on some googled examples but they don't work and I clearly don't understand stages, agent, what environment the `steps {sh '...'}` command runs in, or any of the Jenkins jargon at all.

What's a minimal jenkinsfile which will pull IMAGE_NAME and run a command with arguments in it?

Answer (score 1):

> minimal jenkinsfile

As long as this is not a "code golf" style question, the following pipeline will do the trick for you:

```
pipeline {
  agent any // modify as needed for an agent that supports container runtime

  stages {
    stage('Pull Image and Run Container') {
      script {
        // pulls image and then executes as container; note bonus example of arguments to container instantiation if needed
        docker.image('IMAGE_NAME').withRun('-e "env_var=env_value" -p 1234:5678') { container -> // container is lambda scope variable which you can reference as needed
          // execute startup
          sh(label: 'Startup', script: '/usr/bin/my_startup arg1 arg2 arg3')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you have a private and/or custom registry, then you will need the [withRegistry](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#custom-registry) block and a registry credentials plugin setup on the Jenkins main server.

Comment: I get `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 9: Method calls on objects not allowed outside "script" blocks. @ line 9, column 7.
         docker.image('IMAGE_NAME')`

Comment: @spraff Yes it is ambiguous sometimes whether the Docker plugin documents library methods or global variable methods; updating answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
docker.image('MY_IMAGE').inside {
  sh '/bin/my-command my-args'
}
```

Apparently this is a Pipeline script, run in a Groovy sandbox in Jenkins 2.150.1.